# On the approximation of distributional derivatives by second order differential coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Please, how to prove the following?

> If $u \in C(\Omega)$, $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ with support $K$ and $\Delta^2$ denotes the second order differential quotient, then
> $$
> \lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_K u (\Delta_{\delta e_i}^2\varphi) \ dx = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_K (\Delta_{\delta e_i}^2 u)\varphi \ dx.
> $$

To recall, the second order differential coefficient of $u$ is
$$
\Delta_h^2u(x_0) = \frac{u(x_0 + h) + u(x_0 - h) - 2u(x_0)}{|h|^2}.
$$

For context, this is the conclusion of the proof of Proposition 1.1 in *Fully Nonlinear Elliptic Equations*, by Caffarelli and Cabré.

I'm really clueless on how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answers due to hints by David Stolnicki

For $h$ small enough so that $(x \pm h) \in \Omega$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int_K u(x)(\varphi(x + h) + \varphi(x - h)) - \varphi(x)(u(x + h) + u(x - h)) \ dx = 0.
\end{align*}
Indeed, making $y = x + h$ we get
$$
\underbrace{\int_K u(x) \varphi(x + h) \ dx}_{\displaystyle = \int_K u(y - h) \varphi(y) \ dy} - \int_K \varphi(x) u(x - h) \ dx = 0,
$$
and analogously for the other terms. Adding and subtracting $2 u(x) \varphi(x)$, taking $h = \delta e_i$ and dividing by $\delta^2$, we get
$$
\int_K u (\Delta_{\delta e_i}^2 \varphi) \ dx = \int_K (\Delta_{\delta e_i}^2 u) \varphi \ dx.
$$
Since the limit as $\delta \to 0$ of the left-hand side exists, so does the right-hand side's, and the equality is proved.